# Show 1st of every month on highcharts

Tags: javascript, date, highcharts

Is there a way to create a chart in highcharts such that the first of every relevant month is displayed? For example in this [chart](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/spline-irregular-time), how can I set the options so that it displays 1 Oct, 1 Nov, 1 Dec, 1 Jan, etc. Its fine if it shows other dates as well, but first of the month is required.

Comment: Actually, when you clicked the edit in fiddle button the example shows what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/spline-irregular-time/

Comment: I also see the example just like what you want. By the way, what do you define as `relevant month` ?

Comment: @SachiTekina Hah, thats a little funny. Didnt notice at all. However, looking through the options I dont see anything specifying that, so Im worried its just pure luck.

Comment: @RodrigoBerriel relevant month just means a month that is in the span of the data. IE if my data spans from March to July, I don't care about Janurary

Comment: Nah, my bad when you try to expand the size it changes.

Comment: The easiest way to do it is set a fix width of the container. On the example, by `800px`.

Comment: @SachiTekina I dont think that works when your series values change. Also its not responsive at all...

Comment: You can also use [tickPositioner](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.tickPositioner) to calculate and return a array of timestamps.

Comment: @SebastianBochan Like I already answered...

Comment: Sorry, I missed that ;)

Comment: @DavidGrinberg Does my post answer your question?

Comment: @DavidGrinberg Please consider accepting my response below if it answers your question

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely possible, although a bit of work.

First of all, you need to make the data you want to use in your graph global. You do this by defining it before you use the `.highcharts()` function. Let's call this global data `var DATA` for now.

We want to use highchart's [`xAxis.tickPositions`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.tickPositions) to get the format you are after. So we need to define these exact ticks. I've written some code to accomplish this (given the global `DATA`):

```
var globalMin = Date.UTC(5000, 1, 1);
var globalMax = 0;
for (i = 0; i < DATA.length; i++) {
    var temp = DATA[i].slice();
    var sorted = temp.sort(function(d1, d2){
        return d2[0]-d1[0];
    });
    var max_date = sorted[0];
    var min_date = sorted[sorted.length-1];
    if (max_date[0] > globalMax)
        globalMax = max_date[0];
    if (min_date[0] < globalMin)
        globalMin = min_date[0];
}

function monthDiff(d1, d2) {
    return d2.getMonth()-d1.getMonth() + (12 * (d2.getFullYear()-d1.getFullYear())) + 2;
}

var ticks = [];
var mind = new Date(globalMin);
var maxd = new Date(globalMax);
for (i = 0; i < monthDiff(mind, maxd); i++) {
    var tempDate = new Date(new Date(mind).setMonth(mind.getMonth()+i));
    ticks.push(tempDate.setDate(1));
}
```

This code creates the array `ticks` which contains the `tickPositions` for in the highcharts definition.

So all that's left is to use this array in the `xAxis` definition:

```
xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime',
    tickPositions: ticks,
    min: ticks[0],                   // Remove this if you want an automatic range
    max: ticks[ticks.length - 1],    // Remove this if you want an automatic range
    dateTimeLabelFormats: {
        month: '%e. %b',
        year: '%b'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Date'
    },
    labels: {
        formatter: function () {
            return Highcharts.dateFormat('%e. %B', this.value);
        }
    },
}, ...
```

Note that I've used a fix here to tackle a [**known bug**](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/1441) and make the `tickPositions` display correctly.

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cyprjdrs/)